# Automatically inserting "Section", "Subsection", etc

Tags: cross-referencing

Is there a package that automatically inserts the ToC level of the reference I inserted?

```
Section 1.1
\label{a}
Subsection 1.1.1
\label{b}
Subsection 1.1.2 
\label{c}
```

So that the text:

```
Blah \superref{a} and \superref{b} and \superref{c}
```

becomes:

```
Blah Section 1.1 and Subsection 1.1.1 and Subsection 1.1.2
```

So that it automatically adapts if I change the level of a label?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package and its `\cref` macro. Note that sectioning levels below `\section` are referred to as "section" by default, but this can be customized.

EDIT: In case you want the first letter of the reference name capitalized, use `\Cref`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\section{First-first}\label{a}

\subsection{First-first-first}\label{b}

\subsection{First-first-second}\label{c}

See \cref{a} and \cref{b} and \cref{c}~\dots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\Cref` is for starting a sentence, akin to `\Citet`. For consistent capitalization, use the `capitalize` package option. Use `noabbrev` to fully spell out the reference names. (See Section 6 of the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/cleveref/cleveref.pdf).)

Comment: If one writes `See \cref{a,b,c}`, the output is `See section 1.1 and subsections 1.1.1 and 1.1.2`. A `\cref` instruction can take multiple inputs, and `cleveref` parses, sorts, and (if necessary) compresses the cross-references on its own.

Answer (score 22):

The `hyperref` package provides `\autoref{<label>}` which inserts the name of the reference type as well. These names can also be changed e.g. redefine `\sectionautorefname` to change the name for sections.

Answer (score 0):

For Muggles like me who want to keep things simple :)

Declare your next-level ultra-custom prefixed reference command:

```
\newcommand{\secref}[1]{Sexy Section \ref{#1}}
```

And then go ahead and use it like this:

```
\section{On Mugglers and boring things}\label{mysweetbigbrainlabel}
...

Remember when I told you what a muggler is? if not read 
\secref{mysweetbigbrainlabel} again.
```

KISS