# Shortcut commands for referencing floats

Tags: macros, floats, cross-referencing, best-practices

I always include the following commands in the preamble of my latex documents to make sure I refer to floats consistently in the text. I was wondering if the community had any thoughts about this, is it a good/bad idea or is there a package which duplicates this functionality?

```
\newcommand{\figref}[1]{Figure~\ref{fig:#1}}
\newcommand{\figsref}[2]{Figures~\ref{fig:#1}~and~\ref{fig:#2}}
\newcommand{\figtoref}[2]{Figures~\ref{fig:#1}~through~\ref{fig:#2}}

\newcommand{\tblref}[1]{Table~\ref{tbl:#1}}
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{Equation~\ref{eqn:#1}}
\newcommand{\esref}[2]{Equations~\ref{eqn:#1}~and~\ref{eqn:#2}}
\newcommand{\etoref}[2]{Equations~\ref{eqn:#1}~through~\ref{eqn:#2}}

\newcommand{\secref}[1]{Section~\ref{sec:#1}}
\newcommand{\charef}[1]{Chapter~\ref{cha:#1}}
\newcommand{\aref}[1]{Appendix~\ref{apndx:#1}}
```

Also, my supervisors insist all Latin expressions are italicised, so this saves me some typing.

```
\newcommand{\etal}{\mbox{\emph{et al.\ }}}
\newcommand{\ie}{\mbox{\emph{i. e.\ }}}
\newcommand{\etals}{\mbox{\emph{et al.\ }'s }}
```

Comment: You could be interested in the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39349/automatically-inserting-section-subsection-etc

Comment: In most cases the use of the word *equation* is not appropriate for mathematical expressions. Strictly speaking an equation is a mathematical expression involving equality.

Comment: I'd *never* pluralize "et. al." which is already plural, since it means "et alii" (with possible declension), that is, "and others".

Comment: @egreg the `'s` could be for the possessive, not for the plural, and, indeed, you are right "et. al." is already plural.

Comment: @Guido I can't easily figure out a massive usage for the possessive; writing `\etal's` would be as easy, in any case, and probably more semantically sound.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package provides you with extra commands:

- `\cref{<key>}` will expand to `figure~\ref{<key>}`, `table~\ref{<key>}`, `equation~\eqref{<key>}` depending on what you refer to.
- `\Cref{<key>}` capitalizes at the start of sentences. (There is a package option that capitalize every "Figure", "Table", etc., if you prefer that style. Use `\Cref` only at the start of sentences.)
- `\cref{eq2,eq1,eq3,eq5,thm2,def1}` produces: `eqs.~(1) to~(3) and~(5), theorem~5, and definition~1`. <sup>[Taken from the package manual]</sup>
- `\crefrange{eq1}{eq5}` gives `eqs.~(1) to~(5)`. <sup>[Taken from the package manual]</sup>
- There is also `\cpageref` which will come in handy if you need to refer to multiple pages.
- `\namecref`
- It works very well with `babel`.
- It does work with [`varioref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref) (it hacks into `varioref`'s commands so you can use it like `\vref`, etc.) and [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) if loaded in the order

  1. `varioref`
  2. `hyperref`
  3. `cleveref`

Regarding the second part of your question, I recommend "[\emph or \textit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1980/16595)".

You may also look at [`xspace`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xspace).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
% Choose one of the two follwing:
  \newcommand{\latinphrase}[1]{\textit{#1}}  % always italic
% \newcommand{\latinphrase}[1]{\emph{#1}}    % italic in roman text, upshaped in italicized text
\newcommand{\etal}{\latinphrase{et~al.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ie}{\latinphrase{i.e.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\etals}{\latinphrase{et~al.}'s\xspace}

\begin{document}\noindent
    \emph{This is \emph{very} important.} -- \emph{This is \textit{very} important}\\
    \emph{You better read Knuth's books, \ie ``The \TeX book''.}\\
    \emph{Read Knuth \emph{et amici.}} -- \emph{Read Knuth \latinphrase{et amici.}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled example]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you when you say "don't use `\emph`. That is used to emphasize, not to italicize". Well, emphasis in LaTeX is nearly universally achieved through italicizing, so there's no difference in the outcome (unless the user employs a highly unusual document class that defines `\emph` to do something else than italicization). To adhere to the LaTeX spirit of things, it's actually preferable to use a command name that indicates its purpose (emphasis) rather than the means by which the purpose is achieved (italicization).

Comment: The question about `\,` or not has already been debated here; it seems to be common in German texts, much less in other typographic traditions.

Comment: If `\emph` is inside a part in italics it will be typeset in roman. `\textit{fisrt \emph{second}}` then we get *first* second.

Comment: @Guido - The ability to have nested `\emph` statements (and LaTeX's ability to switch between upright and italics depending on the level of nesting) would be another reason for preferring use of `\emph` to `\textit`, right?

Comment: @Mico Typically you do not switch off italics for latin expressions in text which is already in italics. for italics used for emphasize your absolutely right that `\emph` is. the right way to go.

Comment: In addition to the other comments don't use `\mbox` in definitions such as `\newcommand{\etal}{\mbox{\emph{et al.\ }}}` using a box there freezes the word space at its natural size and so it will look out of place on a line in which other spaces have been stretched or shrunk. Also `\emph` normally looks ahead and adds italic correction `\/` as needed to allow space for switching between italic and upright font shapes, but the box layer will defeat this lookahead.

Comment: Thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel for the suggestion of cleveref and the update to the Latin shortcuts.