# When referencing a figure, make text and figure name clickable

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

When referecnging a figure, you write something like:

```
\begin{figure}[here]
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{images/example.jpg}
\caption{A figure}
\label{figureExample}
\end{figure}
```

and to reference this figure you can just write "an example is figure \ref{figureExample}", and then you will get a text like

> an example is figure 2.1

where 2.1 will be clickable. Now to my question; if I want both the text "figure" and the "2.1" to be clickable, how can I achieve this?

Comment: `autoref` provided by package `hhyperref`?

Comment: [Automatically inserting "Section", "Subsection", etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39351)

Comment: The only problem with auto ref is that it automatically use the labels in english. Any way to get it to use another language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities:

- Load the `hyperref` package and use the `\autoref` macro of that package;
- in addition to loading `hyperref`, load the  `cleveref` package with the option `nameinlink`, and use the `\cref` macro to generate the cross-references.

One of the nifty aspects of `\cref` is that you can call several objects all in one go; the package will take care of any sorting and compressing needs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\section{In the beginning} \label{sec:begin}
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{images/example.jpg}
\caption{A figure} \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:pyth}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

\section{Next}

As was discussed in \autoref{sec:begin} and shown in \autoref{fig:example}, \dots

\bigskip\noindent
As argued in \cref{sec:begin,fig:example,eq:pyth}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! As said in the comment above:The only problem with auto ref is that it automatically use the labels in english. Any way to get it to use another language? –

Comment: @miniHeessel - Is there any language in particular you're interested in?

Comment: Norwegian, so for example instead of figure : figur. Instead of Table :tabell

Comment: @miniHeessel - You're in luck if you use `\cref`: just load `cleveref` with the option `norsk`, and the sentence in the example above will come out as "... avsnitt 1, figur 1 og likning (1) ...". (I'm afraid `cleveref` doesn't recognize the option `nynorsk`...)