# How could we make a table a hyperlink clickable in a LaTeX document?

Tags: tables, hyperref, cross-referencing

I need to make the word "Table" within paragraph clickable.

I have tried this [When referencing a figure, make text and figure name clickable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230828/when-referencing-a-figure-make-text-and-figure-name-clickable). But I got "???" instead.

[image]

Comment: Use the `cleveref` package and `\Cref{tab:foo}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Automatic way, see the `\autoref` feature of `hyperref`:

```
from the \autoref{tab:first}
```

Manually with `\hyperref`:

```
from the \hyperref[tab:first]{Table \ref*{tab:first}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Heiko and @Christian I got what I want.

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
    \usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{makecell}


    \begin{document}

    here text here text here text here text here \autoref{tab:Table1} text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text  .... Similarly to the concluded idea from the \cref{tab:Table1} Table 1 .... here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text  

    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{aaa} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{111} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{222} \\
    \cline{2-3} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{333} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{444} \\
    \cline{2-3} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{555} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{666} \\
    \cline{2-3} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{777} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{888} \\
    \hline
    \ttfamily aaa & \ttfamily bbb & \ttfamily ccc \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Table 1}
    \label{tab:Table1}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]