# Have "Figure", "Table"... word generated automatically when referencing

Tags: cross-referencing

Is there a way to get `\ref` generate also the "word", not only the number?

As in: `Using \ref{eq:gauss}, we can now prove`

I'd like this to turn into `Using Equation 1, we can now prove`.

Right now it just generates the number and I need to write the word `Equation` myself.

Not sure if this is related, but in my "header" file I have this:

```
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[
    unicode=true,
    bookmarks=true,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    bookmarksopen=false,
    breaklinks=false,
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
    pdfpagemode=UseNone,
    backref=false,
    colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
```

I believe it colours the numbers, not really sure.

Comment: Check out the [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package (there are others too, I think).

Comment: looks good, I'll look into that

Comment: @MightyPork: But `\usepackage{cleveref}` **after** `\usepackage{hyperref}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically inserting "Section", "Subsection", etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39349) — the answer is for sectioning elements but `cleveref`/`varioref` works with both.