# Is there a way to use \ref like \href

Tags: cross-referencing

Question is as in the title.

Using \href, we will be able to give a "clickable" link along with text. Can we do the same with \ref. Suppose I want to refer an equation with label \label{equation:123}, I usually write Equation \ref{equation:123}. Is there a way to write something like \ref[Equation]{equation:123} or \ref{Equation}{equation:123} similar to \href{00}{00}?

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\textheight 9.3in \textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} 
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma} 
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}
\newcommand{\og}{\omega}
\newcommand{\tb}{\textbf}
\newcommand{\m}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\Spec}{\rm Spec}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\author{someone}
\title{something}
\begin{document}
\section{qwerty}\label{qwerty}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at `cleverref`

Comment: Unrelated, `\rm` has been obsolete since 1993. I'd use `\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}` instead

Comment: `hyperref` lets you do `\autoref{qwerty}`, but the `cleverref` package may be better, See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39349/automatically-inserting-section-subsection-etc

Comment: One important note. The package name is `cleveref` with **one** r, not two (just finished the cross referencing section of my book last week).

Comment: it is unclear which printed text you want and where it should lead to. And your example is quite useless as it doesn't have any reference in it.

Comment: @DonHosek Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @daleif I did not know about \rm being obsolete. I will use \Declare** from now

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I already mentioned in the question. I want Equation (equation number) when I write \ref{123} and I do not want to write Equation \ref{123} everytime

Comment: but this is not what \href does. \href is for free text. So why do you ask for something similar to \href?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that is the closest I can think of..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to use the `cleveref` pacakge (note that it's just **one** r in the name). You will want to load it with the `nameinlink` option in conjunction with `hyperref`:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
```

You can then write `\cref{equation:123}` in place of `equation~\ref{equation:123}`. Use `\Cref` for capitalization. If `cleveref` inserts abbreviations where you'd prefer it did not, you can add the option `noabbrev` to prevent abbreviations.

Further information can be had by typing `texdoc cleveref` at a command line.

Comment: Thank you.  As of now I do not see any problem :D This is exactly what I want.

Comment: Can this be used to refer multiple equations at a time? something similar to \cite{**,**,**}?

Comment: Yes, you can write, e.g., `\cref{ref1,ref2,ref3}`.  Or to refer to a range write `\crefrange{ref1}{ref2}`.  See the documentation for lots more information.

Comment: This is very nice.. Thank you so much :)

Comment: one last question.. for some diagrams I am using \begin{equation} \label{diagram} \end{equation}.. So, if I use \cref{diagram}, I will get Equation (diagram number) and not Diagram (diagram number).. Is there an easy answer to this or shall I ask it as a  separate question?

Comment: That's a separate question.

Comment: asked https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597612/using-cref-for-diagrams-and-equations

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add cleveref to an already bloated preamble...

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\myref}[2]% #1=added text, #2=label name
  {\hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{anchor}{Doc-Start}}{#1~\ref*{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
  x=a
\end{equation}

\myref{Equation}{eq:1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you :) Can you also look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597612/using-cref-for-diagrams-and-equations