# using \cref{**} for diagrams and equations

Tags: cross-referencing

Thanks to the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597602/165931), which suggested me to use \cref{} to refer sections, definitions etc.

I am using \begin{equation} \end{equation} for both equations and diagrams. So, when I use \cref{}, I am getting Equation (reference number) for diagrams. Is there a way to fix it?

Please find the minimal working example after suggestion of Willie Wong

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

%%% Packages
% 1. fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % recommended
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage{fix-cm} % for Computer Modern (comment if using the next line)
%\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % for Palatino
%\usepackage{upgreek} % do you need it?
%\usepackage{charter} % it has no support for math
%\usepackage{relsize} % do you need it?
\usepackage{a4wide}
% 2. Math
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
% 3. Graphics and special effects
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{shadow}% do you need it?
\usepackage{fancybox}% do you need it?
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

% 4. Document formatting
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newcounter{diagram}
\newenvironment{diagram}{\setcounter{diagram}{\value{equation}}\refstepcounter{diagram}}{}

\begin{document}
    
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    
    \include{Title} 
    
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \bigskip{}
    \vspace{1cm} \cleardoublepage 
    
    
    
    \begin{diagram}\label{diagram:diagram}
        \begin{equation}
            \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
                A \arrow[dd] \arrow[rrr]  & & & B \arrow[dd] \\
                & & &       \\
                C \arrow[rrr]  & & & D   
            \end{tikzcd}    
        \end{equation}
    \end{diagram}
    
    
        \begin{diagram}
        \begin{equation}\label{diagram:diagram1}
            \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
                A \arrow[dd] \arrow[rrr]  & & & B \arrow[dd] \\
                & & &       \\
                C \arrow[rrr]  & & & D   
            \end{tikzcd}    
        \end{equation}
    \end{diagram}

    \begin{equation}\label{eqn:equation}
        y = mx + c
    \end{equation}
    
    \Cref{diagram:diagram}
    \Cref{diagram:diagram1}
    \Cref{eqn:equation}
    
    
    
    
\end{document}
```

Please find attached output

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what is giving you the error. Your MWE is super long and it will take someone a bit of time to find the error. But try the following. change the definition of the diagram environment to `\newenvironment{diagram}{\setcounter{diagram}{\value{equation}}\refstepcounter{diagram}}{}`. It is a lot less fancy: to use it you just put `\begin{diagram}... \end{diagram}` around the `\begin{equation}\begin{tikzcd}...\end{tikzcd}\end{equation}` that you already have. But move the `\label` to **before** `\begin{equation}`.

Comment: @WillieWong PLease find the edit. It is showing error, one of the lines being "No counter 'diagram' defined. \begin{diagram}".

Comment: well you are missing the `\newcounter{diagram}` from the answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes :) Sorry.. I added now.. Still having some trouble...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: you also need to make cleveref aware of the new counter. The answer provided by Willoughby has three lines that start with `\cref...` you need also those three lines. (Paste them in immediately after the `\newenvironment` line.

Comment: @WillieWong Yes. I added it now. It is working but I am not getting chapter/section name, that usually happens for \ref{**}.. Please find the CW answer.. Please see if you can help..

Answer (score 3):

[image]

We can define a new `diagram` environment and make it work with `cleveref`.
I assumed that you want the counter to be the same for both equations and diagrams.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newcounter{diagram}  % Create counter for diagrams

% Create diagram environment
\newenvironment{diagram}[1][]{%
    \begin{equation}%
    \begin{tikzcd}[#1]%
    \setcounter{diagram}{\theequation}
    \addtocounter{diagram}{-1}
    \refstepcounter{diagram}
}{%
    \end{tikzcd}%
    \end{equation}%
}
% Add cleveref information for diagram
\crefname{diagram}{diagram}{diagrams}
\crefname{diagram}{Diagram}{Diagrams}
\creflabelformat{diagram}{(#1) #2 #3}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}\label{eqn:equation}
        y = mx + c
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{diagram}[row sep=2cm, column sep=3cm] \label{dia:diagram}
        A \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & B \arrow[d]\\
        C \arrow[r] & D
    \end{diagram}
    \Cref{eqn:equation} \Cref{dia:diagram}
\end{document}
```

### Explanation

First we define a new counter, `diagram`.
Whenever `cleveref` 'sees' this counter it will know that we want a diagram label.
We then define an environment, `diagram`.
This includes a `tikzcd` environment inside a `equation` environment.
The `equation` environment ensures that the numbering and spacing is the same as for equations.
Note that any optional arguments passed to the `diagram` environment are passed on to the `tikzcd` environment.
We then set the counter `diagram` to be the same value as the `equation` counter.
We then subtract one and then in a single step increment and reference the `diagram` counter (this is why we needed to subtract one first). By doing this *after* the `equation` environment starts we ensure that the `\label` command 'sees' the `diagram` counter.
We then end the environment by closing the two environments we opened.

To make `cleveref` work with the `diagram` environment there are a couple of things we have to do.
First we need to tell `cleveref` what word to use in place of 'Equation', this is done with

```
\crefname{<type>}{<singular>}{<plural>}
```

in this case `<type>` is the counter we are referencing, so `diagram` and `<singular>`/`<plural>` are the singular/plural form of the word.
The next line is the same but uses `\Crefname` which defines the capitalised version of the word.
We could get away with defining just upper or just lower case and then `cleveref` will work out the other version but its simple enough to define both and if the name was more complicated then `cleveref` may fail to find the correct capitalisation.
The final thing we have to do is use

```
\creflabelformat{<type>}{<format>}
```

to tell `cleveref` how to print the label, in this case `<type>` is the counter `diagram` again and format is `(#1) #2 #3` which puts brackets around the number and the other two have to do with getting `hyperref` to work with `clveref`, which can be seen from the red links in the image (simply remove `colorlinks` from the `hyperref` options to get rid of the colour).

I've taken the liberty of removing blank lines in the example diagram and instead setting `row sep` and `column sep`.

Comment: for some reason, it is not working. I am still getting Equation (reference number)

Comment: Without seeing your code its not possible to say why, I suggest you post a new question and put all of your code in it asking why it doesn't work. As an aside your '[minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)' is not very minimal, take out any code that isn't needed to compile the document and reproduce the issue.

Comment: I am using \begin{tikzcd}\end{tikzcd} for diagrams. Is it not different from \begin{diagram} \end{diagram}?

Comment: The way that I've defined the `diagram` environment above includes the `tikzcd` environment, notice in the example usage that there is no `tikzcd` explicitly in the main body of the document but the definition of `diagram` includes `\begin{tikzcd}` and `\end{tikzcd}`. If this is undesirable you can remove the `tikzcd` environment `\begin` and `\end` from the definition of `diagram` and then use them in the document nesting them as `\begin{diagram} \begin{tikzcd} ... \end{tikzcd} \end{diagram}`. So replace all `\begin{equation}\begin{tikzcd}` with `\begin{diagram}` and do the same for `\end...`

Comment: I am using \documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}. Sorry for not mentioning it before. Would that be a reason for not working? I have added the code I am using. \begin{diagram} \end{diagram} is not even working. DId I place them at a wrong place?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: you should be more precise about what you mean by "is not even working". Did you get an error message?

Comment: @Willoughby I believe the `diagram` definition may fail to work with `amsmath` (which redefines how equation numbers are displayed, and labels applied).

Comment: @WillieWong Yes, I should have said more clearly.. I have added the error message I got in the question.

Comment: @Willoughby please see if you can help me with edited question..

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. If you know a way to fix the issue I mentioned, please consider answering that as well.

Answer (score 2):

When a counter is printed (in a caption, equation number, or using `\ref` or `\cref`) LaTeX uses the internal macro `\thecountername` for the various counter names, for example `\theequation` for the equation number and `\thechapter` for the chapter number.

This macro is the connection between the counter and the output in the document, the counter itself is an internal variable and the macro controls how this variable is printed: in arabic or roman numerals for example, but also if there is any other information added in the printed form, such as the section or chapter number.

When you make a new counter with `\newcounter{diagram}` then LaTeX automatically creates the macro `\thediagram`, which is defined by default as `\arabic{diagram}`, so the arabic number and nothing else. This definition is picked up by `\Cref`, so only `(1)` is shown. However, it is possible to redefine `\thediagram` yourself after you make the counter:

```
\newcounter{diagram}
\def\thediagram{\thechapter.\arabic{diagram}}
```

In this definition the chapter counter is printed first, then a period, then the arabic representation of the diagram counter itself. This is very similar to how `\theequation` is defined by LaTeX itself.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newcounter{diagram}
\def\thediagram{\thechapter.\arabic{diagram}}

\newenvironment{diagram}{\setcounter{diagram}{\value{equation}}\refstepcounter{diagram}}{}

\crefname{diagram}{diagram}{diagrams}
\crefname{diagram}{Diagram}{Diagrams}
\creflabelformat{diagram}{(#1)#2#3}

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{Diagrams and equations}

\begin{diagram}\label{diagram:diagram}
  \begin{equation}
      \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
          A \arrow[dd] \arrow[rrr]  & & & B \arrow[dd] \\
          & & &       \\
          C \arrow[rrr]  & & & D   
      \end{tikzcd}    
  \end{equation}
\end{diagram}


\begin{diagram}
  \begin{equation}\label{diagram:diagram1}
      \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
          A \arrow[dd] \arrow[rrr]  & & & B \arrow[dd] \\
          & & &       \\
          C \arrow[rrr]  & & & D   
      \end{tikzcd}    
  \end{equation}
\end{diagram}

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:equation}
  y = mx + c
\end{equation}

\Cref{diagram:diagram}
\Cref{diagram:diagram1}
\Cref{eqn:equation}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that I removed the spaces in the `\creflabelformat` specification, the spaces were showing in the output.

Comment: I did not thought it is this difficult to get what I want :D Suppose I am drawing a diagram in section 1 of chapter 2 then, I would get it as 2.1.1. If I write an equation after that, I will get the equation number as 2.1.2. If I draw another diagram, I would get it as 2.1.3... But, using above label, I am getting as Diagram 2.1 for first diagram and Diagram 2.3 for second diagram... Is there a way to fix it? I tried \def\thediagram{\thechapter. \thesection. \arabic{diagram}}.. It is showing as 2.1.1.1..which is not what I want.. I am extremely sorry for not clarifying it before..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik `\thesection` is defined as `\thechapter.\arabic{section}`, so that already includes the chapter number. So in this case you need `\def\thediagram{\thesection.\arabic{diagram}}`. Note that this does not work outside of a section, i.e., you start a chapter, first type some text with a diagram, then you start the first section of that chapter. You can either add a check for that in the definition of `\thediagram` (which is a bit complex to do right), or never use diagrams outside of sections, or change the definition when needed at the start of a new chapter or new section.

Comment: Ok. I think I should not have done this. This is becoming complicated. I will follow the usual procedure of writing Diagram \ref{something} and Equation \ref{something}..

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

%%% Packages
% 1. fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % recommended
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage{fix-cm} % for Computer Modern (comment if using the next line)
%\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % for Palatino
%\usepackage{upgreek} % do you need it?
%\usepackage{charter} % it has no support for math
%\usepackage{relsize} % do you need it?
\usepackage{a4wide}
% 2. Math
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
% 3. Graphics and special effects
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{shadow}% do you need it?
\usepackage{fancybox}% do you need it?
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

% 4. Document formatting
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newcounter{diagram}
\newenvironment{diagram}{\setcounter{diagram}{\value{equation}}\refstepcounter{diagram}}{}

\crefname{diagram}{diagram}{diagrams}
\crefname{diagram}{Diagram}{Diagrams}
\creflabelformat{diagram}{(#1) #2 #3}

\begin{document}
    
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    
    \include{Title} 
    
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \bigskip{}
    \vspace{1cm} \cleardoublepage 
    
    \chapter{chapter 1}
    
    \begin{diagram}\label{diagram:diagram}
        \begin{equation}
            \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
                A \arrow[dd] \arrow[rrr]  & & & B \arrow[dd] \\
                & & &       \\
                C \arrow[rrr]  & & & D   
            \end{tikzcd}    
        \end{equation}
    \end{diagram}
    
    
    \begin{diagram}
        \begin{equation}\label{diagram:diagram1}
            \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
                A \arrow[dd] \arrow[rrr]  & & & B \arrow[dd] \\
                & & &       \\
                C \arrow[rrr]  & & & D   
            \end{tikzcd}    
        \end{equation}
    \end{diagram}
    
    \begin{equation}\label{eqn:equation}
        y = mx + c
    \end{equation}
    
    \Cref{diagram:diagram}
    \Cref{diagram:diagram1}
    \Cref{eqn:equation}
    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Diagram (reference number) is coming, but, it is not taking chapter/section number. Please see the attached photo.

Is there a way to get chapter/section number?

Comment: you shouldn't bury a question in a answer. It would have much better it you had opened a new question.

Comment: beside this: you are only missing `\renewcommand\thediagram{\thechapter.\arabic{diagram}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct if I got anything wrong, because to me the request sounds weird. You want the label to always refer to the number of the diagram, even if you have nested numbered elements?

Because this would simply lead me to `\let\refstepcounter\stepcounter` within the environment. But I'd still suggest to then create an environment which is already nesting the equation and use `\tag` so the equation is accessing the diagram counter instead of the equation counter.

Full example would be…

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % recommended

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}




\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

%as posted by Willoughby which I wouldn't do different
% Add cleveref information for diagram
\crefname{diagram}{diagram}{diagrams}
\crefname{diagram}{Diagram}{Diagrams}
\creflabelformat{diagram}{(#1) #2 #3}

\newcounter{diagram}
\newenvironment{diagram}{\setcounter{diagram}{\value{equation}}\refstepcounter{diagram}%
    %let all labels within diagram be set to the diagram counter
    \let\refstepcounter\stepcounter
}{}

\renewcommand{\thediagram}{\thesection.\arabic{diagram}}% or replace \thesection by \thechapter
%or if you don't want to use the chapter
%\renewcommand{\thediagram}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{diagram}}

%add resetcounter to equation

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{section}% might be replaced by chapter
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}% might be replaced by \thechapter
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{to have a chapter number}
    \section{to have a section number}
    \begin{diagram}\label{diagram:diagram}
        \begin{equation}
            \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
                A \arrow[dd] \arrow[rrr]  & & & B \arrow[dd] \\
                & & &       \\
                C \arrow[rrr]  & & & D   
            \end{tikzcd}    
        \end{equation}
    \end{diagram}
    
    
    \begin{diagram}
        \begin{equation}\label{diagram:diagram1}
            \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
                A \arrow[dd] \arrow[rrr]  & & & B \arrow[dd] \\
                & & &       \\
                C \arrow[rrr]  & & & D   
            \end{tikzcd}    
        \end{equation}
    \end{diagram}
    
    \begin{equation}\label{eqn:equation}
        y = mx + c
    \end{equation}
    
    \Cref{diagram:diagram}
    \Cref{diagram:diagram1}
    \Cref{eqn:equation}
    
    \chapter{to have a chapter number}
    \section{to have a section number}
    \begin{diagram}\label{diagram:diagram}
        \begin{equation}
            \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
                A \arrow[dd] \arrow[rrr]  & & & B \arrow[dd] \\
                & & &       \\
                C \arrow[rrr]  & & & D   
            \end{tikzcd}    
        \end{equation}
    \end{diagram}
    
    
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image: updated screenshot including section number]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Please see my CW answer.. I want to get Diagram 1.1 and not just Diagram 1..

Comment: didn't see that, (the discussion is a bit hard to follow) but that's straightforward then and no big deal, i changed the `\theequation`and `\thediagram`and adjusted them to be reset each section. But basically I needed to know if there might be more than one equation inside a diagram environment, because this might lead to a different requirement of the use of the counters.

Comment: I added the section number as reset, because somewhere upwards i fount that, in the question you posted as an answer yourself you ask for chapter … i guess you're able to replace that yourself in that case.